Order of a matrix in $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K/2)$, where $K$ is an abelian number field
Let $\zeta_n$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity, and $\alpha_n := \zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1}$, $K := \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_n)$. The ring of integers of $K$ is $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.
The matrix $A := [[-1, -2-\alpha],[1, 1+\alpha]]$ has eigenvalues $\zeta_n^{\pm 1}$ and hence is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ with order $n$.
What is the order of $A$ in $GL_2(\mathcal{O}_K/2)$?
Clearly $A$ has order dividing $n$. If $n$ is odd, then $A$ has order exactly $n$. If $n = 2^rm$, where $r\ge 1$ and $m$ is odd, then by passing to a residue field above $(2)$, we find that the order is divisible by $m$. Moreover, the order is at most $n/2$, since $-I \equiv I \mod 2$. Theorem 1.1 in this paper claims that the order is exactly $n/2$ (when $n$ is even). Why is this true?

Have you looked at the proof in the paper?
